# Adding computers to LogonWorkstation for list of users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking to add two workstations to a list of users.
The user list is `accounts.txt` and the workstations are `server01`, `server02`.

I'm running this script from my win 7 machine, I don't have Domain admin privs but I do have permissions to add the workstations manually to each user in AD.

PS Version is 4

```
ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content C:\Users\myusername\Documents\accounts.txt))
    { 
         $user.LogonWorkstations += ",server01, server02" 
         Set-ADUser -instance $user
    }
```

Full error is:

```
The property 'LogonWorkstations' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:3 char:6
+      $user.LogonWorkstations += ",server01, server02"
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Set-ADUser : The instance parameter object must be of type: 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser'.
At line:4 char:6
+      Set-ADUser -instance $user
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The instance parameter object must be of type: 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manage 
   ment.Commands.SetADUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the `LogonWorkstations` on the username *string* that you read from the file this cannot work. Instead, you have to retrieve the `ADUser` using the [Get-AdUser](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301397) cmdlet where you can access the property.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
$users = Get-Content "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\accounts.txt"
ForEach ($user in $users)
{ 
    $adUseruser = Get-ADUser $user -Properties *
    $adUseruser.LogonWorkstations = @($adUseruser.LogonWorkstations, 'server01', 'server02') -join ','
    Set-ADUser -instance $adUseruser 
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the response, Im running into this error

`Set-ADUser : The instance parameter object must be of type: 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser'.
At line:6 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -instance $user
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The instance parameter object must be of type: 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manage 
   ment.Commands.SetADUser`

Comment: yeah, I had a typo there. Try again

Comment: Not sure why but AD-User is looking for a computer name?

`Set-ADUser : The format of the specified computer name is invalid
At line:6 char:5
+     Set-ADUser -instance $adUseruser
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The format of the specified computer name is invalid,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser`

Comment: Its probably because there are no logonworkstations and you started with a `,`. I changed my script, try again.

Comment: Thanks Martin, your new version works.

I'll need to try and figure out how it works, I'm rather new to this.